# Let f be analytic on ∆

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is: let $f$ be an analytic function on $\Delta$ and satisfy $|f|<1$. Prove that if $f(1/2)=f(−1/2)=0$, then $|f'(0)|\le 1/4$.

I tried to expand $f$ at $0$ and then plug in $1/2$ and $-1/2$ to evaluate the bound. It is quite straight forward if I use $f^{(n)}(0)/n! < 1$. But I got the bound to be $1/3$. Is there some key I am missing here?

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $f \in \operatorname{Hol}(D)$, $f(\frac{1}{2}) + f(-\frac{1}{2}) = 0$, prove that $|f(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177230/if-f-in-operatornamehold-f-frac12-f-frac12-0-prove) – Ooops, no, that is different. Sorry!

Comment: Hint: consider the functions $T_a \colon z \mapsto \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ for $\lvert a\rvert < 1$. What do you know about these functions? How can $T_{\pm 1/2}$ help?

Comment: Is it really $|f'(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$,  or is it $|f(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: @Keba it is the open unit disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer I dont see how everything connects to $f'(o)$

Comment: @MartinR It's $f'(0)$

Comment: @hoper: Then I was wrong in flagging as a duplicate, and I apologize for not reading your question correctly. – However, I think that one can proceed similarly, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(One can proceed similarly as in [If $f \in \operatorname{Hol}(D)$, $f(\frac{1}{2}) + f(-\frac{1}{2}) = 0$, prove that $|f(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177230/if-f-in-operatornamehold-f-frac12-f-frac12-0-prove).)

It is actually sufficient to require that $f(\frac 12)=f(−\frac 12)$
instead of $f(\frac 12)=f(−\frac 12)=0$.

$(f(z) - f(-z))/2$ is an *odd* function in $\mathbb D$ (the unit disk). It follows  that there exists
a holomorphic function $g$ in $\mathbb D$ such that
$$
  z \, g(z^2) = \frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{2} \, . \tag 1
$$
Taking the derivates gives
$$
  g(z^2) + 2 z^2 g'(z^2) = \frac{f'(z)+f'(-z)}{2}
$$
and for $z= 0$ it follows that
$$
  g(0) = f'(0) \, .   
$$

$f(\frac 12)=f(−\frac 12)$ implies $g( \frac 14) = 0$, and 
 $|g(z)| < 1$ in $\mathbb D$ follows from the Schwarz lemma applied to
the right-hand side of $(1)$.

Then
$$
  h(z) = g \bigl(\frac{z + \frac 14}{1+ \frac 14 z} \bigr)
$$
satisfies $|h(z)| < 1$ in $\mathbb D$ and $h(0) = 0$.

It follows from Schwarz lemma that $|h(z)| \le |z|$ in $\mathbb D$ and in particular
$$
 \frac 14 \ge |h(-\frac 14)| = |g(0)| = |f'(0)| \, .
$$

The example
$$
  f(z) = z \, \frac{z^2 - \frac 14}{1 - \frac 14 z^2} 
$$
with $f(\frac 12) = f (-\frac 12) = 0$ and $f'(0) = -\frac 14$ shows that the bound
$|f'(0)| \le \frac 14$ is best possible.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: By taking the derivatives in (1) and then setting $z = 0$. – I have extended the answer.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: The RHS of (1) – let's call it $r(z)$ – satisfies $r(0) = 0$ and $|r(z)| < 1$. It follows from the Schwarz Lemma that $|r(z)| \le |z|$. $|r(z)| = |z|$ for some $z$ would imply $r(z) = az$ for some $a$ with $|a|=1$, this contradicts $r(1/2) = 0$. – Therefore $|r(z)| < |z|$ for all $z$ and $|g(z^2)| = |r(z)|/|z| < 1$.