# Let $f: D(0,1) \to D(0,1) $ a holomorphic map which is also continuous on the boundary of the disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(0,1) \to D(0,1) $ a holomorphic map which is also continuous on the boundary of the disk.
Let there exists $a\in D(0,1)$ such that $f(a)=f(-a)=0.$

Show that $$|f(0)|\le |a|^2.$$

I don't understand how to use continuous at boundary thing.

Whatever I have done so far is the following :
$f$ analytic in and on disk of radius $|a|$  center at $0 . $
Power series of $f(z)$ about $0$ is $$f(z)=a_0+a_1z^2+....$$
$$f(a)=f(-a) \implies f(z)=a_0+a_2z^2+... $$
Now, $f(a)=0 \implies a_0=-(a_2a^2+....)$
So, $|f(0)|=|a^2||(a_2+....)|$
Unable to conclude anything from this . Need help to solve this problem.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509179/42969, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94122/42969 for a generalization.