# Find a holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z(\pi-z))=\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

While studying for a test I have encountered this problem,

Is there a holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z(\pi-z))=\sin(z)$, $(\forall z\in \mathbb{C})$?

I thought of developing a Taylor series for $\sin(z)$ and $g(w)$ around $w,z=0$,
saying coefficients must be equal for same degree variable $z$.

It doesn't seem to work for me though... Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you asking for $g(\pi z-z^2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$
z(\pi - z) = \frac {\pi^2}{4} - \left(z - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2
$$
so with the substitution $z - \frac{\pi}{2}= w$ your identity is equivalent to
$$
 g\left(\frac {\pi^2}{4} - w^2\right) = \cos(w)
$$

Now use the fact that the cosine is an *even* function, therefore
$\cos(w) = h(w^2)$ for some entire function $h$.
Then $g : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ defined by
$$
 g(u) := h\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4} - u\right)
$$
is the desired solution.

Comment: Thank Martin, But why can you assume existence of such a function $h$? How does the fact that cosine is even help you?

Comment: @Daniel: You can (for example) use the fact that the power series of the cosine has only *even* coefficients. See the final part of http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1177343/42969 for an explicit construction.

Comment: Many thanks  :))